# Search in Datatable (ServerSide) sql query with "Grouped by" Statement

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable

I am using [datatable](http://datatables.net) jQuery plugin to render multiple joined tables from MySQL database. I am able to get the table rendered as desired. But the search is not functioning.

**Observations:**
When I tried to run the query in my dbms using the "WHERE" clause, I found that the "WHERE" clause will only run if it is coming before the "GROUP BY" statement. So in my code it must also come before the "GROUP BY" statement, whereas the $sql is concatenating the "WHERE" clause after the "GROUP BY" statement. I don't know how to insert the WHERE clause (with search value) before the "GROUP BY" statement at runtime.

I am providing the code for both of my files, (1) **Index.php** (the file with the table and the js which sends ajax request to response.php file). (2) **response.php** (the file containing the sql and search code which sends json encoded data to index.php). I am using the datatable version 1.10.10. I am following this [tutorial](http://phpflow.com/php/datatable-pagination-sorting-and-search-server-side-phpmysql-using-ajax/)

Following is my code:

**index.php**

```
<head>
...
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/customize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
...
</head>
<body>
...
  <div class="row">
    <div id="" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <table id="employee_grid" class="display table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
             <th class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">Student Name</th>
             <th class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Gender</th>
             <th class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">City</th>
             <th class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Course Description</th>
             <th class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">Subject</th>
             <th class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 text-right">Scholarship</th>
             <th class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">View Details</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
       </table>
     </div>
   </div>
...
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#employee_grid').DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "stateSave": true,
        "lengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 100 ],
        "ajax":{
                url :"response_b.php", // json datasource
                type: "post",  // type of method,GET/POST/DELETE
                error: function(){
                $("#employee_grid_processing").css("display","none");
                }
            },
        "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": 6,
        "data": "StudentID",
        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
        return '<a href="beneficiary.php?StudentID="'+data+'">'+data+'</a>';
        }
     }]
  });   
});
</script>
</body>
```

**response.php**

```
<?php
    //include connection file 
    include_once("connection.php");

    // initilize all variable
    $params = $columns = $totalRecords = $data = array();

    $params = $_REQUEST;

    //define index of column
    $columns = array( 
        0 => '`Full Name`',
        1 => 'Gender', 
        2 => 'CityName',
        3 => 'CourseDescriptionLong',
        4 => '`Subject`',
        5 => 'ScholarshipAwarded',
        6 => 'StudentID'
    );

    $where = $sqlTot = $sqlRec = "";

    // check search value exist
    if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {   
        $where .=" WHERE ";
        $where .=" (`Full Name` LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";    
        $where .=" OR CityName LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";

        $where .=" OR CourseDescriptionLong LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' )";
    }

    // getting total number records without any search
     $sql = "
        SELECT fullnames.`full name`, 
           studentdetails.gender, 
           lt_cities.cityname, 
           lt_coursedescription.coursedescriptionlong, 
           lt_coursesubject.`subject`, 
           Sum(scholarshipdetails.scholarshipawarded), 
           studentdetails.studentid, 
           coursedetails.coursetype, 
           lt_coursedescription.coursedescriptionshort, 
           scholarshipdetails.scholarshipyear 
    FROM   studentdetails 
           INNER JOIN scholarshipdetails 
                   ON studentdetails.studentid = scholarshipdetails.studentid 
           INNER JOIN coursedetails 
                   ON studentdetails.studentid = coursedetails.studentid 
                      AND scholarshipdetails.scholarshipyear = 
                          coursedetails.scholarshipyear 
           LEFT JOIN lt_coursedescription 
                  ON coursedetails.courseid = lt_coursedescription.courseid 
           INNER JOIN tuitionfeedetails 
                   ON studentdetails.studentid = tuitionfeedetails.studentid 
                      AND scholarshipdetails.scholarshipyear = 
                          tuitionfeedetails.scholarshipyear 
           INNER JOIN fullnames 
                   ON studentdetails.studentid = fullnames.studentid 
           INNER JOIN lt_cities 
                   ON lt_cities.cityid = studentdetails.city 
           LEFT JOIN lt_coursesubject 
                  ON lt_coursesubject.courseid = lt_coursedescription.courseid 
                     AND lt_coursesubject.subjectid = coursedetails.coursesubject 
    GROUP  BY studentdetails.studentid";
    $sqlTot .= $sql;
    $sqlRec .= $sql;
    //concatenate search sql if value exist
    if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

        $sqlTot .= $where;
        $sqlRec .= $where;
    }


    $sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY ". $columns[$params['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$params['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$params['start']." ,".$params['length']." ";

    $queryTot = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTot) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));


    $totalRecords = mysqli_num_rows($queryTot);

    $queryRecords = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch employees data");

    //iterate on results row and create new index array of data
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($queryRecords) ) { 
        $data[] = $row;
    }   

    $json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $params['draw'] ),   
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ),  
            "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
            "data"            => $data   // total data array
            );

    echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
?>
```

I have researched for this type questions on the Stack Overflow, and there are many questions with answers, but none of them seems to work for me.

Can any one guide me?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code for **GROUP BY** query after **WHERE** condition.

```
<?php
    //include connection file 
    include_once("connection.php");

    // initilize all variable
    $params = $columns = $totalRecords = $data = array();

    $params = $_REQUEST;

    //define index of column
    $columns = array( 
        0 => '`Full Name`',
        1 => 'Gender', 
        2 => 'CityName',
        3 => 'CourseDescriptionLong',
        4 => '`Subject`',
        5 => 'ScholarshipAwarded',
        6 => 'StudentID'
    );

    $where = $sqlTot = $sqlRec = "";

    // check search value exist
    if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {   
        $where .=" WHERE ";
        $where .=" (`Full Name` LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";    
        $where .=" OR CityName LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";

        $where .=" OR CourseDescriptionLong LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' )";
    }

    // getting total number records without any search
    $sql = "SELECT fullnames.`Full Name`, studentdetails.Gender, lt_cities.CityName, lt_coursedescription.CourseDescriptionLong, lt_coursesubject.`Subject`, Sum(scholarshipdetails.ScholarshipAwarded), studentdetails.StudentID, coursedetails.CourseType, lt_coursedescription.CourseDescriptionShort, scholarshipdetails.ScholarshipYear FROM studentdetails INNER JOIN scholarshipdetails ON studentdetails.StudentID = scholarshipdetails.StudentID INNER JOIN coursedetails ON studentdetails.StudentID = coursedetails.StudentID AND scholarshipdetails.ScholarshipYear = coursedetails.Scholarshipyear LEFT JOIN lt_coursedescription ON coursedetails.CourseID = lt_coursedescription.CourseID INNER JOIN tuitionfeedetails ON studentdetails.StudentID = tuitionfeedetails.StudentID AND scholarshipdetails.ScholarshipYear = tuitionfeedetails.ScholarshipYear INNER JOIN fullnames ON studentdetails.StudentID = fullnames.StudentID INNER JOIN lt_cities ON lt_cities.CityID = studentdetails.City LEFT JOIN lt_coursesubject ON lt_coursesubject.CourseID = lt_coursedescription.CourseID AND lt_coursesubject.SubjectID = coursedetails.CourseSubject ";
    $sqlTot .= $sql;
    $sqlRec .= $sql;
    //concatenate search sql if value exist
    if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

        $sqlTot .= $where;
        $sqlRec .= $where;
    }

   $sqlRec .=  "  GROUP BY studentdetails.StudentID ";
    $sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY ". $columns[$params['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$params['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$params['start']." ,".$params['length']." ";

    $queryTot = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTot) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));


    $totalRecords = mysqli_num_rows($queryTot);

    $queryRecords = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch employees data");

    //iterate on results row and create new index array of data
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($queryRecords) ) { 
        $data[] = $row;
    }   

    $json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $params['draw'] ),   
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ),  
            "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
            "data"            => $data   // total data array
            );

    echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
?>
```

Comment: I just implemented the changes suggested by you @bhavin-solanki, but its not working. I think my observation is mis-leading and there is some other problem with the search function.

Comment: if the error was of where condition it should solve now

Comment: I have few quick question :  why here a space between `Full Name`,  $columns = array( 0 => '`Full Name`',

Comment: Why space here too : $where .=" (`Full Name` LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";